# Group only a particular section in Crystal Reports?

Tags: c#, asp.net, crystal-reports

I want to show the all the details of a particular cashsafe in crystal reports.Since the report is for a certain cashsafe the values wont be repeating.
The report format is as follows:

```
cashsafeid:1
cashsafename:Aromaa
cashsafecode:1234
...
```

Along this i have to show the details of holiday of a particular cashsafe

```
Holidays:
  Repeating:
    Holiday:        01    Date:   01/01
    Holiday:        02    Date:   01/01
    Holiday:        03    Date:   01/01
  Non-Repeating
    Holiday:        01    Date:   01/01/3333
    Holiday:        02    Date:   01/01/3333
    Holiday:        03    Date:   01/01/3333
```

To display in above format i have grouped the data based on Holidayschedule(Repeating or nonrepeating).But the problem is that after each value in the group field the enitre cashsafe is repeating.After grouping crystal report shows the data in the following format

```
cashsafeid:1
cashsafename:Aromaa
cashsafecode:1234
...
 Holidays:
  Repeating:
    Holiday:        01    Date:   01/01
cashsafeid:1
cashsafename:Aromaa
cashsafecode:1234
...
 Repeating:      
    Holiday:        02    Date:   01/01
cashsafeid:1
cashsafename:Aromaa
cashsafecode:1234..
```

Is grouping possible in the above scenario?If possible how can only a particular section inside a whole group?If grouping is not possible how can i show the holidays in the below format?

```
cashsafeid:1
cashsafename:Aromaa
cashsafecode:1234
...
 Holidays:
  Repeating:
    Holiday:        01    Date:   01/01
    Holiday:        02    Date:   01/01
    Holiday:        03    Date:   01/01
  Non-Repeating
    Holiday:        01    Date:   01/01/3333
    Holiday:        02    Date:   01/01/3333
    Holiday:        03    Date:   01/01/3333
```

Comment: `Below format`?... there is no format below that statement

Comment: Sorry updated the question now.

Answer (score 0):

go to field explorer and click group name fields and prompt show select particular field to group your data.